# Paperclip images not being shown in Production mode in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Development, it is working fine but in production mode, the images are not visible and I am getting "The page you were looking for doesn't exist" error. I have put this code in initalizers/paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!(
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", 
    :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
)
```

and have recompiled resources with

```
rake assets:precompile
```

still the images are not being shown in production mode. Any help ?

EDIT - OK I got it, the paths were not accurate. Also you may want to enable config.serve_static_assets = true in config/environment/production.rb if you are running it in production on localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, there were two mistakes -

1. The paths were not accurate so I fixed them
2. Also you may want to enable config.serve_static_assets = true in config/environment/production.rb if you are running it in production on localhost

Comment: Not recommended to enable `serve_static_assets`, more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30198348/868003