# Asset Precompilation OK, but 404 when trying to get files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Ok so compiling my assets is working fine but when I run:

`thin start -e production`

none of my javascript or css is loading. My browser is also cancelling the requests to get my assets. I'm not sure why this is but I suspect its because it thinks its 404'ing on them. If you look at the top image you'll see that my application.css file was compiled and stored in my assets folder but when I try to access the file, I'm getting my 404.html file.

What gives!?

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

I was asked to post my view. Here is some of the code in the project:

```
<% content_for :title, 'Quick Quote' %>
<% content_for :subtotal, get_subtotal %>
<% content_for :stylesheet_includes do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "quote", "jquery-ui-timepicker-addon" %>
<% end %>
<% if @quote.errors.any? %>
  <div class="flash alert">
  <% @quote.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <div><%= msg %></div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<h1>Quick Quote</h1>
```

**my layout:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= (yield(:title) + " - " unless yield(:title).blank?).to_s + "Online Scheduler Order Taker" %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", "jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css", :media => "all" %>
  <%= yield :stylesheet_includes %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= yield :javascript_includes %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
```

**code in my production.rb**

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( quote.css jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css prices.css contact.css )
```

**Top of my application.css.scss.erb:**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *
 * require_tree . <- commented out
 * require jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css <- commented out
 */
```

**my entire application.js file**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Can you please post the (presumably View, or CSS) code where you reference the assets?

Comment: Done. Added what I thought was relevant. I'm not doing anything interesting in my css but I am using coffeescript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your `config/environments/production.rb` file and add next line to it (if it does not have it yet):

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Comment: I think you should not follow this approach! see the comment mentioned by @TechFuel. That says why you should not be doing that

Comment: Update for Rails 5: `config.public_file_server.enabled = true`

Answer (score 10):

Rails recommends that this setting `config.serve_static_assets` by default should be disabled i.e. set to false. Here is the default configuration in `config/environments/production.rb` generated in rails app

#### Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)

`config.serve_static_assets = false`

So if you are setting it to `true` in your local app then that's still fine. But if you are deploying your app on Apache or ngix or anything other than heroku then its not advisable to make `config.serve_static_assets=true` in your `production.rb` config file. Here is the documentation in Rails guides.

> config.serve_static_files configures Rails itself to serve static
>   files. Defaults to true, but in the production environment is turned
>   off as the server software (e.g. NGINX or Apache) used to run the
>   application should serve static assets instead. Unlike the default
>   setting set this to true when running (absolutely not recommended!) or
>   testing your app in production mode using WEBrick. Otherwise you won't
>   be able use page caching and requests for files that exist regularly
>   under the public directory will anyway hit your Rails app.

URL - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Answer (score 4):

Rails 5:

Change `config.public_file_server.enabled` in `production.rb` to `true` or add `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES` with any value to env variables.

Reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18100

Answer (score 3):

Can you put this line in your current environment.rb?

```
config.serve_static_assets=true
```

Reference: [here](http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/04/untangling-the-rails-asset-pipeline-part-4-troubleshooting/)

Comment: I think you should not follow this approach! see the comment mentioned by @TechFuel. That says why you should not be doing that.